# Binding wx Frames together

Tags: python, windows, wxpython

I'm making a replacement for a very out of date application at work written in possibly Delphi (don't have source code) and decided to use Python with wx.

The old one behaves such that when you alt+tab or peek on the task bar icon it only shows the main window as an entry but if you bring it to front all other windows created by it are brought up as well.

In wx every subframe I open becomes it's own entry and you have to manually focus each and every one. Is there a way to achieve the above-mentioned behavior with wx?

I tried setting the main frame as a parent but that didn't do nothing.

Comment: please post a minimum working example

Comment: It depends somewhat on the platform standards, but give the wx.FRAME_TOOL_WINDOW style a try on all the frames other than the main frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my model was go through login to a 'Mainframe', sort of a task panel from where you'd open up other windows. These 'Subframes' were each a wx.Frame with wx.Panel in them.

Simply changing the subFrame1(wx.Frame) to subFrame1(wx.Dialog) solved my issue - the dialogs do not appear in the alt+tab menu, nor in taskbar and upon selecting the Mainframe everything is brought to front.